# Selecting distinct rows from a table with several similar rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to list all cars that are available for rent between two specific dates, using a procedure. The table of which I am to select from, bookings, looks similar to this;

```
CarNumber    StartDate    EndDate
1            2018-01-03   2018-01-05
2            2018-01-09   2018-01-14
3            2018-01-03   2018-01-04
2            2018-01-29   2018-02-2
3            2018-01-12   2018-01-16
```

This is my current procedure;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE available_cars (Start_Date DATE, End_Date DATE)
READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT CarNumber FROM bookings
        WHERE NOT StartDate BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
           OR NOT EndDate BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date;
    END;
```

This, to my knowledge, correctly checks if the car is rentable between, Start_Date and End_Date, the issue is that it cannot take into account several rows with the same CarNumber. For example, if I were to call the procedure with the dates 2018-01-10 to 2018-01-12 the output will display;

```
CarNumber
1
3
2
```

Obviously Car 3 and Car 2 is not available to be rented between these dates, but due to the table including several bookings on several rows it checks the second booking as well.

So how do I account for this?

Comment: The reason why i am using a procedure is because our professor wants it to be done with a procedure... No reason to downvote my post due to this nor MCRE, i've provided the table of wich i select from and the procedure that interacts with it.

Comment: Maybe you were downvoted because you didn't provide create table and insert statements so others could work on your problem. Or maybe because some people don't like homework problems posted. Who knows?

Comment: It's not homework in that sense, this specific task is just for practice. I don't really know what you mean, i'm pretty much working with the things i provided in the post? The only difference is that my list of bookings is longer. How about instead of telling me i did wrong you provide feedback on how to do it the next time? I don't see what i did poorly when describing my issue.

Comment: I did provide a table and i got no clue what you mean with an insert statement. Was my question hard to understand as it is written now? Also, i don't know what SO means.

Comment: Your question is not hard to understand. You didn't provide the inputs needed for somebody to work with your data. Did you provide a create table statement so your table could be easily created by those willing to work on your problem? No. Did you provide sample data as insert statements for those willing to work on your problem? No. If you don't understand these things perhaps you should stick to asking your professor for help. He probably already has the table with data, unlike the rest of us.

Comment: The data table is literally in the question posed. If the question is easyto understand, then i dont see the issue. If you read the question carefully you'll realize that i didnt ask anyone to solve the issue, i asked for how to account for something specific.

Comment: You literally didn't provide the data table. A data table is comprised of a CREATE TABLE statement, and one or more INSERT statements. Note that the rule for overlaps is simply that Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. The accepted answer is incorrect in this respect.

Comment: @Strawberry, you are right. I missed that point. I fixed my answer.
LinusLiljequist, you did not provide sufficient resources to work on your problem. Data means queries that allow to test solution.

Comment: I feel as providing any more of my code is superflous since it doesn't relate to the answer i was looking for. I didn't ask for solutions in terms of code, i did not ask anyone to alter my code, i did not ask anyone to improve my code. I asked specifically how to account for something. So the burden you are putting on my questions is unnecessary and does not relate to the problem i wanted to be solved, in this respect Tajniak did not solve my question by providing code, but by providing a explanation as to why i cannot account for this without unique key it did.

Comment: Lastly, i just want to say that the specific example i gave was just to contextualize the issue i was experiancing, it was not the issue itself. The issue was not me being unable to solve the task, it was me being unable to account for this specific scenario with my current knowledge. Again, i urge you to read my question as i specifically state "the issue is that it cannot take into account several rows with the same CarNumber", the issue isn't me being unable to complete the task.

Comment: I *urge* you to read this: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I did and it doesn't apply to my issue according to me, as my issue actually did not have anything to do with any of the code i provided to contextualize the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't store unique key in your database you can make compound query checking rented cars between selected dates and then making a DIFF between all available cars and currently rented.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CarNumber
FROM bookings
WHERE CarNumber NOT IN (
        SELECT CarNumber FROM bookings
        WHERE StartDate BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
        OR EndDate BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date)
        OR (StartDate < Start_Date AND EndDate > End_Date;
```

You can easily create procedure from that code.

Comment: Thanks! This work around solved the issue i was experiancing, is it possible to do this without a unique key or with this work around?

Comment: Probably not. You need to have full list of cars the rental has in service. And anyway there is risk that some cars have been never rented, so you will not list them anyhow.